# How to make admingenerator ignore empty fields in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, admin-generator

I'm currently struggling with the Symfony 2 AdminGenerator. I try making a basic admin user management form, and this includes editing of user data. In there I have field email, password and isActive. Problem is that password is saved even if empty, which is not what I want it to do.

I need the password to be taken into account ONLY if anything is entered, otherwise it should be ignored and this field should not be populated.

Thank you in advance, as I found no info on AG in Symfony 2 regarding this issue,
Boyan.

Comment: Just save the old password in a temporary variable (before you bind the request to the form) and then compare it with the "new" password, i.e. `if ($user->getPassword() === null) { $user->setPassword($tempPass)}`.

Comment: What is the form field type of the password field?

Comment: The form field is of type "password". And @mahok it doesn't work, as I try to check it on pre-save event and all I'm given is the new password ONLY... and I can't just save the object 'cause it's already pre-populated with the new password "".

Comment: See my answer as it wouldn't fit into a comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had in mind:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function editAction($id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:User')->find($id);
        if (!$user) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
            $oldPassword = $user->getPassword();
            $form->bindRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                if ($user->getPassword() === '' || $user->getPassword() === null) {
                    $user->setPassword($oldPassword);
                } else {
                    // Encode password
                }
                $em->flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before you bind the request to the form, you save the password in a temporary variable. Then you check, whether the new password is null or '' or whatever, you either replace it with the old password or encode it. I'm not sure how your admin generator looks, but this would be a way to solve this.

You could also look into FOSUserBundle. FOSUserBundle:user uses a property plainPassword, which when updating the user via FOSUserBundle/UserManager is encoded and replaces the real password, if it's not empty.

**update**: the action is obviously missing some parts, like redirecting after successful edit and rendering the form... just a quick hack to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you, two months later :)
Best way of doing this is binding a class that implements the EventSubscriberInterface to the pre-bind event in the form object. Using this methods you don't have to edit the controller of the admin generator.

[Suscriber Listener Ignore Empty fields](http://www.rjguevara.com/2013/02/symfony-2-ignorar-campos-vacios-en.html), the link is in spanish, but I can translated to you, basically you create a class that implements the EventSubscriberInterface  interface, the blog post gives you the class:

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\Admin;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class IgnoreBlankFieldListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $factory;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory, $name)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->name = $name;
}

public static function isNotEmpty($var )
{
    if(is_array($var))
    {
        $notempty = false;

        foreach( $var as $v )
        {
            $notempty = $notempty || !IgnoreBlankFieldListener::isNotEmpty($v);
        }

        return $notempty;
    }
    else
        return !empty ($var);
}

public static function isEmpty( $var )
{

    return IgnoreBlankFieldListener::isNotEmpty($var);
}

public function preBind(FormEvent $event){
    $data = $event->getData();
    $data_name = $data[$this->name];

    if( IgnoreBlankFieldListener::isEmpty($data_name) )
    {
       $form = $event->getForm();
       unset( $data[$this->name] );
       $event->setData($data);
       $form->remove($this->name);
    }
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents() {

        return array(FormEvents::PRE_BIND => 'preBind');
    }
}
```

Then, you suscribe this class to the form, you do this in the buildForm part of the ClassType definition:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
 //initial code
 //
$subscriber = new IgnoreBlankFieldListener($builder->getFormFactory(), 'password');

$builder->addEventSubscriber($subscriber);

}
```

More info in [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)